# Error: A required parameter (id) was missing when redirect URL in form Moodle

Tags: block, moodle

Moodle 3, developing a block

I'm getting the following  error: 'A required parameter (id) was missing'.

It happens in $mform, only when I'm using the array('id' => $instance->id) in the 'Else if' statement in the redirect($url).

Surprisingly, because when I'm using the same code in a button with a redirect url, the code works correct.

I've tried several things, but nothing helps. What could be the problem?

Here is some code:

```
$id = required_param('id', PARAM_INT);

$instance = $DB->get_record('block_instances', array('id' => $id), '*', MUST_EXIST);

$context       = \context_block::instance($instance->id);

$mform = new newlink();

if ($mform->is_cancelled()) {

     $url = new moodle_url('/my');

     redirect($url);

} else if ($fromform = $mform->get_data()) {

// data from form

....

$url = new moodle_url('/blocks/name_of_block/links.php', array('id' =>  $instance->id)); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    (Note: when I'm using here the block instance id number 123 directly, the redirect is working correct:

     $url = new moodle_url('/blocks/name_of_block/links.php?id=123';)

     redirect ($url);

} else {

 //Set default data (if any)

$mform->set_data($toform);

//displays the form

$mform->display();

}

$url = new moodle_url('/blocks/name_of_block/links.php', array('id' => $instance->id))

echo $OUTPUT->single_button($url, get_string('button:links', 'block_name_of_block')); // THIS IS WORKING CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it when you submit the form rather than the redirect?

In your form do you have:

```
$mform->addElement('hidden', 'id');
$mform->setType('id', PARAM_INT);
```

and in the code above do you have:

```
$toform->id = $id;
$mform->set_data($toform);
```

Comment: It seems rather on submitting than on redirect. But when checking the URL the block instance ID is not added to the URL.

Comment: It seems rather on submitting than on redirect. But on checking the URL the block instance ID is not added to URL. I've based my code on a tutorial ([link](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/tablelib.php)) and added code e.g. to delete rows from table. This is working, after I added the instance ID in the URL. But whatever I do, adding a new record in the table is only possible when I put the instance ID hardcoded in the redirect URL. Btw, in the Moodle tutorial there is no blockinstance id used. In my code I have no hidden $mform element, I've tested with that but the problem still remains.

Comment: You should probably use `optional_param()` rather than `required_param()`

Comment: problem solved, your answer was part of the solution. After checking code I've altered something else, and now it works with the required parameter.